# Why is apache2 not configured

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

I am trying to install the `mod_wsgi` module in apache to deploy a django project.

I am using the pre-installed `apache2` in `ubuntu`.
After I installed the module, I was asked to verify if apache is loading properly the module by executing `apache2ctl -M`:

```sh
comon@mylocal:~$ apache2ctl -M 

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully    qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

And it seems that there is no `mod_wsgi` so I found that I need to add `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` in the `httpd.conf` configure file in apache.

To know where this file is located, I ran: `/usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE` AND I go:

```sh
comon@mylocal:~$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE

[Mon Jan 25 12:04:39.169687 2016] [core:warn] [pid 7614] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Jan 25 12:04:39.169748 2016] [core:warn] [pid 7614] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Mon Jan 25 12:04:39.169766 2016] [core:warn] [pid 7614] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Mon Jan 25 12:04:39.169773 2016] [core:warn] [pid 7614] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Mon Jan 25 12:04:39.169790 2016] [core:warn] [pid 7614] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Jan 25 12:04:39.171891 2016] [core:warn] [pid 7614:tid 139649371690880] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Jan 25 12:04:39.172022 2016] [core:warn] [pid 7614:tid 139649371690880] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Jan 25 12:04:39.172037 2016] [core:warn] [pid 7614:tid 139649371690880] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

It seems that nothing is conigured in my `apache2`!

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Look's you have problem with you variables on apache, check the file apache2.conf for line's like "Define APACHE_LOCK_DIR /some/path/", look the as configured to use those varibales but they are not defined anyware. For the mod_wsgi, you can use "a2enmod mod_wsgi

Answer (score 0):

Use apachectl, not apache2/httpd executables directly, to pick up the customized environment variables sourced by apachectl on your distribution of apache.